# Spiritual meaning of splitting of sea?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, yetziat-mitzrayim

In [this video:](http://yybm.esy.es/)  Can someone explain what he says about the splitting of the sea was really a splitting of spiritual "words" Where exactly are these words and how can they "split"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video explains that the concept of the splitting of the sea to reveal the bottom and make it possible for the Children of Israel to walk through is like revealing the basic meaning of the universe. The concept is that the words we use in the Torah to describe the world are like the sea that we see filling the ocean. On a spiritual level, the *essence* of the universe is basically hidden by the physical universe that we see and that is made up of the "words" used to cause it to come into being.

The splitting of the sea is being used as a metaphor for the revealing of the intrinsic nature of the universe. This is done by going deeper and deeper into the building blocks of the universe, like seeing the quantum foam behind the physical time/space continuum.

Comment: Who's idea was it?